# Convert case sensitives

Tags: django, case-sensitive

i want to convert any new enter user name to lowercase and check if the user is exist or now and use iexact to login in capital or small
where should determine the login uses small or capital

forms.py

```
class AddCompanyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    Add company model form
    """
    name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    logo = forms.ImageField(required=False)
    phone_number = forms.CharField(widget=forms.NumberInput())
    label = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    country = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Country.objects.all())
    city = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=City.objects.all())
    area = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Area.objects.all())
    latitude = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=False)
    longitude = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=False)
    water_source = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=WaterSource.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['name', 'username', 'email', 'password']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AddCompanyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.layout = Layout(Row(Column('name', css_class='form-group col-md-6 mb-0'),
                                 Column('username', css_class='form-group col-md-6 mb-0'), css_class='form-row'),
                             Row(Column('email', css_class='form-group col-md-6 mb-0'),
                                 Column('password', css_class='form-group col-md-6 mb-0'), css_class='form-row'),
                             Row(Column('phone_number', css_class='form-group col-md-6 mb-0'),
                                 Column('logo', css_class='form-group col-md-6 mb-0'), css_class='form-row'),
                             Row(Column('label', css_class='form-group col'), css_class='form-row'),
                             Row(Column('country', css_class='form-group col'),
                                 Column('city', css_class='form-group col'), Column('area', css_class='form-group col'),
                                 css_class='form-row'), Row(Column('latitude', css_class='form-group col'),
                                                            Column('longitude', css_class='form-group col'),
                                                            css_class='form-row'),
                             Row(Column('water_source', css_class='form-group col'), css_class='form-row'))
        self.helper.layout = self.layout
```

views.py

```
class Companies(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, FormView, ListView):
    """
    Company add edit delete view search paginator
    """
    model = Company
    template_name = 'company/index.html'
    form_class = AddCompanyForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('companies:index')
    object_list = Company.objects.all()

def form_valid(self, form):
    user, created = User.objects.get_or_create(username=form.cleaned_data['username'],
                                               email=form.cleaned_data['email'])
    user.set_password(form.cleaned_data['password'])
    user.save()
    if created:
        address = Address(label=form.cleaned_data['label'], city=form.cleaned_data['city'],
                          area=form.cleaned_data['area'], long=form.cleaned_data['longitude'],
                          lat=form.cleaned_data['latitude'], country=form.cleaned_data['country'])
        address.save()

        company = Company(owner=user, name=form.cleaned_data['name'],
                          phone_number=form.cleaned_data['phone_number'], logo=form.cleaned_data['logo'],
                          address=address, water_source=form.cleaned_data['water_source'])
        company.save()
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

am try to put this function in form to convert lowercase

```
def clean_username(self): 
 return self.cleaned_data['username'].lower()
```

how i can use iexact when login and where

Comment: Why don't you put lower() here? 
User.objects.get_or_create(username=form.cleaned_data['username'].lower(), ...
so when you search for the name in the database it is already in lowercase letters

Answer (score 0):

you can match username in lowercase like this

```
from django.db.models.functions import Lower

input_name = form.cleaned_data['username'].lower()

User.objects.annotate(username_lower=Lower("username")).filter(username_lower=input_name)
```